# Android Fragment top level Layout is not programatically accessible

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I cannot reach the top level '' of a fragment by the id given to the layout in its xml, it turns out to be a null object. But I can access the parent of its child views. That parent is not the layout itself, but rather the '' containing the layout. And when I programatically add children to this fragment they don't align with the already present children, suggesting those actually are within a nested Layout.

This behaviour really puzzels me. Can anyone explain what is happening?

I declare a top level fragmented layout like this:

> Sibling fragments and layout settings stripped for readability

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_view"
>
    <fragment
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:name="foo.bar.foobar.fragments.ShowWeightsFragment"
    android:id="@+id/show_weights_fragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/frag_show_weights"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

`layout/frag_show_weights` is defined as follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/layout_container_weights"
>

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Foo"
    android:id="@+id/xmlTextChildren"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The MainActivity.java looks like the following

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xmlTextChildren);
    t.setText("Foo");

    LinearLayout parentLayout = (LinearLayout)  findViewById(R.id.xmlTextChildren).getParent();
    LinearLayout layoutFromID = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_container_weights);

    TextView v = new TextView(this);
    v.setText("Bar");
    if (layoutFromID == null) Log.d(TAG, "Layout from ID is null");
    Log.d(TAG, "ID parent name: " + getResources().getResourceEntryName(parentLayout.getId()));
    parentLayout.addView(v);
}
```

The Log output is following:

> 08-22 12:06:24.855: D/MainActivity(2346): Layout from ID is null
>
> 08-22 12:06:24.856: D/MainActivity(2346): ID parent name: show_weights_fragment

And the actual emulator output shows that the two texts don't align, which makes me assume they are not contained within the same `<LinearLayout>`
[image: The emulated output on Android 5.22 running on a Nexus 5]

Comment: I tried to move the request for the layout to the fragments `onStart()`. There all layout elements should have been created and be available. Still the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short Answer: use the id `R.id.show_weights_fragment` of your fragment to access its view if you've set an id within `<fragment>`.

---

[The documentation for Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding) has a statement for the handling ids of fragments:

> **Note**: Each fragment requires a unique identifier that the system can use to restore the fragment if the activity is restarted (and which you can use to capture the fragment to perform transactions, such as remove it). There are three ways to provide an ID for a fragment:
>
> - Supply the android:id attribute with a unique ID.
> - Supply the android:tag attribute with a unique string.
> - If you provide neither of the previous two, the system uses the ID of the container view.

This motivates the assumption, that it just works the other way around, if the id for the fragment is set. I couldn't find documentation about this, but [the sources for `FragmentManagerImpl`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-5.1.1_r13/core/java/android/app/FragmentManager.java#2071) show, that this assumption holds:

```
public View onCreateView(View parent, String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    if (!"fragment".equals(name)) {
        return null;
    }

    [...]

    int id = a.getResourceId(com.android.internal.R.styleable.Fragment_id, View.NO_ID);
    String tag = a.getString(com.android.internal.R.styleable.Fragment_tag);

    [...]

    if (id != 0) {
        fragment.mView.setId(id);
    }
    if (fragment.mView.getTag() == null) {
        fragment.mView.setTag(tag);
    }
    return fragment.mView;
}
```

This is also, what your log is showing: `parentLayout.getId() == R.id.show_weights_fragment`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move you code from onCreate to onCreateView.

From Android doc:

"Standard implementation of onCreateView(View, String, Context, AttributeSet) used when inflating with the LayoutInflater returned by getSystemService(Class). This implementation handles tags to embed fragments inside of the activity."

Comment: I assume that answer was just a wild guess. But I tried it and the results were the same.